# Substituição de palavras especificas

Tags: php, string, criptografia, echo

Quero criar um código em PHP no qual o usuário digita por exemplo "pedro foi ao mercado" ele substitua em algumas palavras já registradas tipo trocar a silaba "mer" por cobre e a silaba "foi" por casa por exemplo. e dar o texto pronto em outra janela.

Não sei por onde começar, qualquer ajuda e bem vinda

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `str_replace`, utilizando `arrays`:

```
$texto  = "pedro foi ao mercado";

$de    = array("mer", "foi");
$para  = array("cobre", "casa");

$novafrase = str_replace($de, $para, $texto);

echo $novafrase;
```

Exemplo funcional: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2471681445c29734cc26afc31e318a9c56d6691

Fonte: [function.str-replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)